# Why does LiveData.getValue return null unless observe has been called?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room, android-lifecycle, android-livedata

I have a `ViewModel` which has a property of type `LiveData<UserData>`, being read from a Room database.

Its code is as follows:

```
class UserDataViewModel(application: Application) : AndroidViewModel(application) {

    private val userDataDao: UserDataDao = AppDatabase.getInstance(application).dao()
    val userData: LiveData<UserData?> = userDataDao.getUserData()

}
```

In the associated activity, I get a reference to the view model:

```
private val viewModel: UserDataViewModel by viewModels()
```

In that activity, I need to get the value of the `UserData` on a button click:

```
private fun handleClick(view: View) {
    viewModel.userData.value?.let {
        // do stuff if the userData is present
    }
}
```

Now in theory, unless the user presses the button before the data has been loaded, this should never be null.

However, as the code stands, the call to `viewModel.userData.value` is always null and the `let` block never executes.

But, **if I add this statement in `onCreate`, the `let` block in the click handler executes as desired**:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    viewModel.userData.observe(this, Observer {
        // do nothing
    })
}
```

My question is: why do I need to call the observe function, even if I'm doing nothing with a change event, to get valid responses from `LiveData::getValue`?

Comment: Why are you using `LiveData` at all if you don't need to observe the data?

Comment: values are emitted when you have observer. That's how live data works

Comment: In this particular instance I'm not observing this data. I am, however, going to be using it in data binding later in development

Comment: @Raghunandan is that to say that if the data binding were already observing the data, my value checks would execute fine without the additional observer in onCreate?

Comment: check null coalescing operator https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/expressions. as already suggested by the answer below livedata initially will be null

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> My question is: why do I need to call the observe function, even if I'm doing nothing with a change event, to get valid responses from LiveData::getValue?

Because the `ComputableLiveData` returned from the Room DAO only executes the query if the LiveData has at least one active observer (inside `LiveData.onActive()`). Then it runs asynchronously on a different thread, and at some point in the future it will be posted into the LiveData.

Comment: Brill, that's exactly the answer I was looking for. Makes sense I guess and it'll become irrelevant in this case when I finish the implementation. Just struck me as odd when I came across it.

Comment: Eventually if you do intend to use the LiveData as part of a binding expression, then the generated binding will register an observer based on the `lifecycleOwner` you provide to the binding. So yes, then you'll have an active observer, and this will stop being an issue.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to call `observe()` in order to get a LiveData to give up a value other than null.  LiveData always contains and yields null initially until something sets its value.  If you don't want this initial null value, then you should immediately set it to something else instead, before making the LiveData available to any other components.  If you want to know when it first contains a non-null value, you will need to use an observer.

Comment: Isn't this being done by this line in the view model? `val userData: LiveData<UserData?> = userDataDao.getUserData()`

Comment: If you do it that way, you're accepting whatever `userDataDao` sets at the initial value, which is null.  You should be observing it instead, so you can know when it first has a non-null value.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it was actually why that wasn't being updated within 1 minute of opening the app (enough time to access the database) that I was looking for - detailed in EpicPandaForce's answer

Comment: Yeah, all LiveData are "inactive" until observed.  They will not give up any data until they become active, or until someone sets the initial value - whichever one comes first.